# Autolayout Issue with Width of a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

```
    signUpButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    signUpButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 128).isActive = true
    signUpButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64).isActive = true
    signUpButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    signUpButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    signUpButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
```

- NSLayoutConstraint: UIButton:'Sign Up'.width == 128   (active),
- NSLayoutConstraint: H:|-(0)-[UIButton:'Sign Up']   (active, names: '|':UIView: ),
- NSLayoutConstraint: UIButton:'Sign Up'.trailing == UIView:.trailing   (active),
- NSLayoutConstraint: 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:.width == 375   (active)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
NSLayoutConstraint: UIButton:'Sign Up'.width == 128   (active)>

**I want to put my button to center of leading and trailing anchors with certain width but when I run the code the button expands to those anchors. How can I prevent that expansion?**

Comment: Unrelated but consider replacing the individual uses of `.isActive = true` with the user of `NSLayoutContraint.activate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems you wish to center the button horizontally within `view`, you need to replace:

```
signUpButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
signUpButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

with:

```
signUpButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```